# AddRange from `await` directly

Tags: c#, async-await, addrange

I am currently returning a list of lists (`List<List<string>>`) from `await getWorlds()` and right now I am looping through each one of them, and getting the first entry in each list.

I just wonder if there is another way I can quickly add all of them directly into `Worlds` with `.AddRange` or something?

Here is my code:

```
var worlds = await getWorlds();
foreach (var w in worlds)
{
    Worlds.Add(w[0]);
}
```

Any way to shorten this to something smaller? Like `Worlds = worlds.AddRange([0]);` or something? I just want to get the first entry `[0]` and add each one to the `Worlds`. I'm just looking to see if there's a cleaner way of writing my code. I have not managed to find any example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var worlds = await getWorlds();
Worlds.AddRange(worlds.Select(w => w[0]));
```

Though I don't see why the `foreach` was so bad.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!!!! I was just looking for best-practices. I am new in C# and I just try to write as little code as possible that does the job for me. Would it even be possible to put it all in one line? and switch `worlds.` to `await getWorlds().`? or something

Comment: @Lee The smallest amount of code is not always the best, it can make it unreadable or hard to understand. Sometimes a simple loop is the best, especially as this code is doing basically the same thing but hiding the loop from you.

Comment: The main thing to remember with stuff like this is that the compiler will likely end up optimising it to the same code underneath anyway - you will almost certainly not achieve anything in terms of performance or efficiency by obsessing over this sort of thing...

Comment: Something like this is starting to get difficult to read: `Worlds.AddRange((await getWorlds()).SelectMany(w => w.Take(1)))`.

Comment: I see. Thanks guys for your help and explanations! I really appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 2):

This is not quite what you're looking for, but you *could* do this to add all instances of items in all the sub-lists too, rather than just the first one.. (this will flatten the list into a single list of items)

```
var worlds = await getWorlds();
Worlds.AddRange(worlds.SelectMany(w=>w));
```